# Why is this conditional removal of WooCommerce billing field not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got the following code in my functions.php file that is supposed to check if certain products are in the cart and, if they are, remove a field from the billing set of fields at checkout. However, it's not removing the field, or any other field I try. I'm wondering why that is. Other tutorials I'm following are consistent with this code and say it should work, but for me it's not. What did I get wrong?

```
/**
 * Check if a specific product ID is in the cart
 */
function dz_product_is_in_the_cart() {
    // Add your special product IDs here
    $ids = array( '10771', '10773', '10774', '10943', '10944', '10945', '10946', '10947', '10948', '10949', '10950', '10951', '10952', '10953', '10943', '10943', '10943', '10943');;

    // Products currently in the cart
    $cart_ids = array();

    // Find each product in the cart and add it to the $cart_ids array
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];
        $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
    }

    // If one of the special products are in the cart, return true.
    if ( ! empty( array_intersect( $ids, $cart_ids ) ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Conditionally remove a checkout field based on products in the cart
 */
function dz_remove_checkout_field( $fields ) {
    if ( dz_product_is_in_the_cart() ) {
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] );
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'dz_remove_checkout_field' );
```

The `billing_first_name` field is a required field. So do I need to do something to unrequire it before I try to `unset` it?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the `$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']` variable to see if there's a "required" (or equivalent) parameter to set it to unrequired/false? Then you could just hide it.

Comment: I added `echo $fields;` to the function but nothing appeared on the page to see whether it's required.

Comment: use `var_dump($fields)` and it'll only be visible on the checkout form page if done in the dz_remove_checkout_field() method (as hooked to woocommerce_checkout_fields)

Comment: Thanks. I got the dump to appear and the `billing_first_name` field is required. I looked at other code examples and it appears that if I add `$fields['billing']['billing_student_name']['required'] = false;` within the condition, it should turn off the required boolean. But it doesn't work when I add that. `["billing_student_name"]=> array(8) { ["required"]=> bool(true)` is still the state of the field.

Comment: I also tried `unset( $fields['billing']['billing_student_name']['required'] );` but that had no effect.

Comment: Can you try this way https://diviengine.com/snippet-make-woocommerce-checkout-fields-not-required/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a plugin that was inserting this field was overriding my code that tried to unrequire and remove it. I opted to disable the plugin and add and conditionally control my own field(s) with the code here: https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-7